# Winui3, How to include folders to packaged installer?

Tags: c#, winui-3, winui

I have a WinUI3 application that should supposed to copy a certain folder structure during installation so that this data is available local on each pc.

How do I implement this so that when I create an AppPackage, the folder structure is also copied when I run the installer?

**Example folder structure which should be also packaged**

- Folder 1

  - Subfolder 1

    - files
  - Subfolder 2

    - files
  - Subfolder 3

    - files

The above folder structure should be present in the installation path of the app on every PC on which the application is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on Visual Studio:

1. Create the folder/sub-folder in the WinUI 3 project.
2. Fill the folder with your files.
3. Right-click a file and select **property**. The **Properties** pane should show up.
4. Set **Copy to Output Directory** to **Copy always** or **Copy if newer**.
5. Do the same for the other files in the folder.

Comment: Thank you, I have done that.

Is it also possible to set a specific output directory? 

I have a packaged app, I can find the appdata of such a packaged app in /User/AppData/Local/Packages/ToolName_IDxx

However, I would now like the tool to store the data in /User/AppData/Local/FolderX, for example, during installation

Comment: Sorry. I'm not sure how to do that. You should open a new question anyway. Somebody might be able to help you out with that.